# View for Header in section with different height in different UITableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

[image]

This is my `Split View Controller` with two controllers. In both I use `UITableView`. In both I implement `tableView(viewForHeaderInSection:)` method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var title = "Some Title"
    return UIView.viewForHeaderInSectionWithTitle(title)
}
```

My `UIView` extesion:

```
extension UIView {
    class func viewForHeaderInSectionWithTitle(title: String) -> UIView? {
        var headerView: UIView?

        headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds), 25))
        headerView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.catskillWhite()

        let frame = CGRectMake(15, 3, CGRectGetWidth(headerView!.frame) - 15, 19)
        let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
        label.text = title
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = UIColor.curiousBlue()
        label.font = UIFont.latoLightFontWithSize(15)
        label.sizeToFit()

        headerView!.addSubview(label)

        return headerView
    }
}
```

So **same source**, but **different** result. Why? The height is different, and label is not centered in the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: from the docs: **The returned object can be a UILabel or UIImageView object, as well as a custom view. This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.** did you implement that method also?

Comment: no, I didn't, because I set the height of header inside my custom method

Comment: but - regarding to the docs - this is not enough. if you implement `viewforheader` you also have to implement `heightforheader` to make it work correctly!

Comment: you were right:-) It is working...